# PHP require stop main script

Tags: php, rest, api

My main.php file require auth.php to authenticated the users:

```
require 'auth.php';
```

But if there is a failure in the authentication, I want to stop/exit also the  execution of the main.php file.

At the moment the script will proceed after the require.

auth.php will exit with:

```
http_response_code(403);
return;
```

Any ideas to stop both scripts at the return?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code/logic which calls `require 'auth.php';` as you only need set a state not return. then in the calling script check it.

Comment: do `exit();` instead of `return;`

Comment: you can use exit(); or die(); instead of return

Comment: or you can use `die()`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that would sound so rude to someone not familiar with PHP

Comment: This would be more rude `die("you have been killed")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further details Ill answer your question.

Instead of returning nothing, return a state.

So:

```
if (bad) {
    http_response_code(403);
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Then in your caller

```
$auth = require 'auth.php';

if (!$auth) {
    // do something to exit out or show/build error
}
```

Or set the state and don't return.

```
if (bad) {
    http_response_code(403);
    $auth = false;
} else {
    $auth = true;
}
```

Then in your caller

```
require 'auth.php';

if (!$auth) {
    // do something to exit out or show/build error
}
```

Comment: if (!$auth) {
   exit();
}

Just needed to add this to main.php and the return bool will be checked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas to stop both scripts at the return?

A raw `exit` only, even with a message, is often not the best approach. It's often better to call a view file for any output to the browser.
For example your `auth.php` is about "authorisation", so it being in charge of setting headers and exiting is not ideal. Really that should be a new class, or at least a function which can return a useful state.

This is ideal and easy when you use classes and a view template, such as twig, but can easily be done with procedural code and files, or just functions to make it easier.

So you could have an "error.php" file which calls the usual things for output, your header/footer, and anything else. Then if at some point there is an error, you could call this file, pass the error message to it and let it show your website layout/css etc and the error message.

main.php:

```
require 'auth.php';

$authError = auth_function();

if ($authError) {
    require 'error.php';
    output_error($authError);
    exit; // You could exit in the error function, but maybe one day you do not want to
}
```

auth.php:

```
function auth_function()
{
    // Do whatever

    if (403) {
        return '403';
    }
    // Can have other "elseifs" here to return other things

    return null;
}
```

error.php:

```
function output_error($error)
{
    // Include all your header/css/body/set header to 403/whatever
    echo "Sorry we found the error {$error}";
    // Include footer etc
}
```